# EF Linq Query working in .NET Core 2.1 doesn't work in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Originally there was this EF Linq query that is being used in our backend

```
return _dbContext.Users.Select(u => new AuthUser
            {
                Email = u.Email,
                Role = u.Role,
            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

However the disabling of implicit client execution means that this query can no longer be translated properly and throws a runtime error.

The exception message and another SO answer say to add a call to `ToListAsync()` into the query to force ICE. I've tried doing this, but now I'm getting compiler errors as the return types are being screwed up because I need to await the task to get the list I can operate on. Which means I need to return a Task, which I'm not doing.

Here's what I have now, which is giving me a compile error on the return type.

```
public async Task<AuthUser> GetAuthUser(string email)
        {     
            var users = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
                
            return  users.Select(u => new AuthUser
            {
                Email = u.Email,
                Role = u.Role,
            }).FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            
            
        }
```

Comment: The exception message *definitely* doesn't say to use client-side evaluation. That's not a solution, that covers up the problem. The original code didn't work in EF Core 2.1 either, nor would it have worked in EF 6.2. Equality in **SQL** depends on the column collation which typically, is case-**in**sensitive. You probably don't need `e.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` at all. Have you tried a simple `e.Email==email` ?

Comment: This is happening daly.  1) Make sure you have the latest APIs and your sample code is latest 2) Make sure you following following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes 3) TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were obsoleted 5 years ago and TLS 1.2 must be used starting in June this year.  So all windows patches need to be installed, Net updated, and Visual Studio needs to support TLS 1.2.  There are many combinations of fixes to force TLS 1.2 (not use 1.0 or 1.1).

Comment: What happened in EF Core 2.1 was that due to missing features, queries that couldn't be translated to SQL were being evaluated on the client *by loading almost all of the data locally*. That's very bad for performance. EF 6.2 didn't have that problem so it didn't use client-side evaluation. What you thought was working was probably loading *all* users in memory and tried to filter them without indexing

Comment: It's so much easier to understand things if you copy/paste the errors (including any error codes) directly into your question.  If they are not in English, paste them as they show up and provide a rough translation into English.  Saying that it's *giving me a compile error on the return type* is meaningless

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToList
Async(). ` Sure seems to me like it's telling me to use ICE.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just tried your suggestion of doing `e.Email == email`, which has worked. Why exactly does this work and the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` doesn't? Is it because this can't be directly translated into SQL so it's falling over?

Comment: `String.Equals` is a .NET function with no equivalent in SQL. In SQL equality and ordering is controlled by the column's collation, eg `Latin1_CI_AS`. A collation also affects which codepage is used to read single-byte text.

Comment: In general, a developer should be looking at the generated SQL.....during the development process.  Here is a breadcrumb on how to wire up logging.......in the context.       https://github.com/granadacoder/oracle-ef-issues-demo/blob/master/src/DataLayer.EntityFramework/Contexts/EfPlaygroundDbContext.cs#L66

Comment: @granadaCoder: A developer can see the generated SQL in the debugger if, instead of *fluently* calling `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList` (or whatever) on the results of an EF query, a temporary variable is used to hold the query results and the final results are materialized by calling `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList` (or whatever) on that variable.  If you look at that temporary variable (with the debugger) immediate after the results are materialized, the SQL should show up. The temporary doesn't cost much - in all likelihood, the optimizer will throw it away.